# After upgrade to 7.2 in Cpanel, some data from table database not showing

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel, php-7.2

I am building web with php laravel  and use cpanel as the server. Previously in cpanel i using php 7.1 everything is working perfectly but i must change to php 7.2, and i have some problem, such as there are some data in from table in database not showing in "select form" but some data from other table can show their value.

i have try to set the setting like php 7.1 like this image, but still not solved
[setting php in cpanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrTDb.jpg)

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? I'm assuming your using Apache, so  you can use .htaccess. If so maybe try adding `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php71 .php` to your .htaccess file. This will keep you running php 7.1

Comment: i use laravel 5.6, where i must add that? i attached my httaccess below, please help

Comment: you should be fine with php7.2, not sure why your having issues, but for a band-aid fix you can go back to your php 7.1 by adding that line of code to the top. Above the '<IModule' code. If above doesn't work try `AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php71 .php` Note the ea. Thats how I do it with some old sites that need php5.6

Comment: Also, update your questions, don't add updated code to the answer section unless it's an answer. They like to keep it clean on SO =)

Answer (score 0):

I use Laravel 5.6
are u mean to edit httaccess in public folder?

here is my httacces

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

where i must add this AddHandler application/x-httpd-php71 .php